# Is the quotient map locally bi-Lipschitz?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, lie-groups

Suppose $G$ is a Lie group of matrices with a subgroup $H$ and a metric $d_G$, and then define the induced metric on $G/H$ as $d_H(g_1 H, g_2 H) = \inf_{h_1, h_2 \in H} d_G(g_1h_1, g_2h_2)$.

I've seen in sources online that the quotient map $\pi: G \to G/H; g \mapsto gH$ is differentiable. I want to know if it is locally bi-Lipschitz. It would be enough (I think) to show that the derivative is bounded on compact sets, but I can't find any information on how to practically compute the derivative of this map. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is not even locally injective, unless $H$ is a discrete subgroup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $G$ is an $n$-dimensional Lie group, and if the subgroup $H$ is itself a Lie group of positive dimension $k < n$, then infinitesmally the projection map $\pi$ is locally modelled on the standard projection $\mathbb R^n \mapsto \mathbb R^k$. This is indeed Lipschitz.

But it is very far from bilipschitz. For example if $g_1 \ne g_2$ then $d(g_1,g_2) \ne 0$. And then if in addition $g_1^{-1} g_2 \in H$ it follows $g_1 H = g_2 H$ and therefore $d_H(g_1 H,g_2 H) = 0$. And for what it is worth, for each $g_1$ one can find $g_2$ so that $g_1 H = g_2 H$ and so that $d(g_1,g_2)$ is arbitrarily close to $0$ (the fact that $g_2$ exists uses that $H$ has positive dimension). So the map cannot even be locally bilipschitz.

The point is that to prove Lipschitz you only need for the derivative to be bounded above, but to prove bi-Lipschitz you need a lot more, namely that the absolute value of the derivative is bounded away from zero by a positive constant.

Comment: Thank you for this - I see now that of course there is no hope of bi-Lipschitz. But my thinking is that if you have $g_1 H = g_2 H$, then $g_1$ and $g_2$ should be ``far'' away from each other, and so this isn't a problem when aiming for local bi-Lipschitz, i.e. bi-Lipschitz when restricted to sufficiently small sets.

Comment: I added some sentences to the end of my second paragraph to rule out even that possibility, assuming that $H$ has positive dimension. I had that in mind from the start and wrote in the hypothesis that $H$ has positive dimension, but then forgot to write out the argument.